# Error when try to connect to telegram bot at spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, telegram

I cant fix problem with my spring boot application, where I tried to create my own Telegram bot.
After Spring container created and app start, I see at logs same error :
    [Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RN8v.png)

> 2019-06-17 23:26:33.117 ERROR 3340 --- [gram Connection] Telegram Bots Api                        : BOTSESSION

[Bot Impl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovI8k.png) :

```
public TelegramBot(BotProperties botProperties) {
    this.botProperties = botProperties;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
    try {
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new TelegramBot(botProperties));
        logger.info("bot successfully register");
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    if (update.hasMessage()) {
        System.out.println(update.getMessage().getText());
    }
}

@Override
public String getBotUsername() {
    return botProperties.getBotName();
}

@Override
public String getBotToken() {
    return botProperties.getBotToken();
}
}
```

Main class :

```
public class TelegramApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        SpringApplication.run(TelegramApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that at a time only one server if accessing the bot . The telegram bot address  can only be accessed by one server at a time.If you are having one in local and one server running in another ,it will throw this same when you try connecting it in local.

If you are using the devtools to rebuild the code without restarting, try to stop the application and restart it.It should work.

Comment: Its common spring bot application, as I understand, when i start it, only one local server up. If i wrong and application start on two servers as you say, maybe u know how to resolve this problem and start only one ?